# Angular 2 - Auth0

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, auth0

I am trying to implement the log in and Sign up from Auth0. I followed these steps from Auth0 website:

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/01-login

I am using Angular 2 RC5

This is how my files looks like:

app.component.html

```
 <div class="navbar-header">
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Auth0 - Angular 2</a>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-margin" (click)="auth.login()" *ngIf="!auth.authenticated()">Log In</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-margin" (click)="auth.logout()" *ngIf="auth.authenticated()">Log Out</button>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Auth} from "./auth.service";

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
constructor(private auth: Auth) {}
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable }      from '@angular/core';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';

// Avoid name not found warnings
declare var Auth0Lock: any;

@Injectable()
export class Auth {
  // Configure Auth0
  lock = new Auth0Lock('MY_CLIENT_ID', 'MY_DOMAIN.auth0.com', {});

  constructor() {
    // Add callback for lock `authenticated` event
    this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult) => {
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
    });
  }

  public login() {
    // Call the show method to display the widget.
    this.lock.show();
  };

  public authenticated() {
    // Check if there's an unexpired JWT
    // This searches for an item in localStorage with key == 'id_token'
    return tokenNotExpired();
  };

  public logout() {
    // Remove token from localStorage
    localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
  };
}
```

But i am getting these errors in my Chrome Developer JavaScript console:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent_Host - inline template:0:0
EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent_Host - inline template:0:0
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Auth!
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: DI Exception
    at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (exceptions.js:27)
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (reflective_exceptions.js:43)
    at new NoProviderError (reflective_exceptions.js:80)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (reflective_injector.js:786)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (reflective_injector.js:814)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (reflective_injector.js:777)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (reflective_injector.js:586)
    at NgModuleInjector.get (ng_module_factory.js:98)
    at DebugAppView._View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal (AppComponent.ngfactory.js:16)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.create (view.js:101)
ERROR CONTEXT:
DebugContext {_view: _View_AppComponent_Host0, _nodeIndex: 0, _tplRow: 0, _tplCol: 0}_nodeIndex: 0_staticNodeInfo: (...)_tplCol: 0_tplRow: 0_view: _View_AppComponent_Host0component: (...)componentRenderElement: (...)context: (...)injector: (...)providerTokens: (...)references: (...)renderNode: (...)source: (...)__proto__: Object
Unhandled Promise rejection: EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent_Host - inline template:0:0
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Auth!
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: DI Exception
    at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:1867:23)
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:29230:16)
    at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:29267:16)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:58584:19)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:58612:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:58575:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:58384:21)
    at NgModuleInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:42059:52)
    at DebugAppView._View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal (AppComponent.ngfactory.js:16:70)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.create (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:59148:21)
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object] ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: ViewWrappedException {_wrapperMessage: "Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent_Host - inline template:0:0", _originalException: NoProviderError, _originalStack: "Error: DI Exception↵    at NoProviderError.BaseExc…e (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:59148:21)", _context: DebugContext, _wrapperStack: "Error: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent_… at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:27889:27"}
Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent_Host - inline template:0:0(…)
```

and the webpage is blank. Nothing appears.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

This is how I implemented and it is working fine Code Geek

**app.module.ts**

```
 import { AUTH_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2-jwt';
 import { Auth } from './services/auth0.service';


    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule
      ],
      providers: [AUTH_PROVIDERS, Auth],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular2Auth0</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="http://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/10.2/lock.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Auth } from './services/auth0.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private auth: Auth) {
    console.log(auth);
  }


}
```

Comment: Here is the sample code for the same https://github.com/MateenKadwaikar/Angular2Auth0GoogleMap

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

`import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

```
constructor(private router: Router) { }

public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: `enter code here`RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (localStorage.getItem('userId')) {
        return true;
    }

    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
    return false;
}
```

}`

Use this in router:
`export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: YourComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
];`

And in login set the local storage:
`localStorage.setItem('userId', id);`

Answer (score 0):

Inside Component metadata , add :-

```
providers: [Auth]
```

[Using services](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html)

Or :-

Include it in your ngModule metadata :-

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {Auth} from 'your path'
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    //your imports
 ],

 bootstrap: [//your component],
 providers: [Auth]
```

})

[Refer here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#angular-dependency-injection)

Answer (score 0):

The steps does not mention but, you need to add following script in your index.html.

```
 <script src="http://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/10.2/lock.min.js"></script>
```

when I did this website started to load up, now I get a different error.

core.umd.js?e2a5:3462 EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:4:70 caused by: Cannot read property 'authenticated' of undefined

I will keep you posted if I am able to solve this.

Comment: I got it working, I have give a different name (instead of auth, I gave authenticated) in the component constructor. silly mistake costed my half an hour.   constructor(private api: ApiService, private auth: Auth) {...}